# TensorFlow Model with Fashion MNIST dataset

Tags: java, python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am very new to [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/). I want to use TensorFlow for my fashion e-commerce site (runs on java) in such a way that all product images should be auto tagged using CNN.

I checked [LabelImage.java](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/examples/LabelImage.java) example using inception5h pre trained tensorflow model for auto tagging/label new images.

It seems that inception5h is not fit for fashion dataset. I also found one guide explained on train first neural network with basic classification used Fashion MNIST dataset.

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification

I also want to create my own model, train it on Fashion MNIST dataset and use it in my java code for auto tagging.

Question -

1. Can we retrain inception5h model for Fashion MNIST dataset as well ?
2. Is there any pre-trained tensorflow model available for fashion dataset ?
3. If I trained the model, can i used the same model in my java code by referring [LabelImage.java](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/examples/LabelImage.java) example ? LabelImage example required model and graph label.

Answer (score -1):

I am just looking into Fashion-MNIST myself. It is said that F-MNIST deliberately imitates all the property that MNIST has and any model trained on MNIST can be used on F-MNIST with just a slight change of dataset path.

Although there is a problem of overfitting while transferring my own MNIST model to a Fashion-MNIST dataset. I'm still checking my code and trying to find out what's wrong.